# CSS columns property ignored in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm using the following CSS property.

```
  -webkit-columns: 2 125px;
     -moz-columns: 2 125px;
          columns: 2 125px;
```

It works fine in most browsers, but I explicit have to support `Safari-5.0.x`. In this browser, the content is shown in two columns as expected, but the width of `125px` is taken as absolute size! Thus, the two columns each are just 125px wide, instead of using 50% of the page.

How could I fix this?

What I noticed: removing the fixed number of columns fixed the issue, but I explicit want to restrict the count of columns to two bejond the 125px size.

**Update**:
Interestingly, if I **only** change the following line, it works:

```
  -webkit-columns: 3 125px;
```

Result: 2(!) columns are shown in safari, and they are aligned as expected (content expands to container size). Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using Bootstrap grid system, it's the most efficient. Especially that MOZ Columns may only work with supported browsers, Bootstrap is recommended for all versions of browser.

Comment: I have to fill the content of the two tabs dynamically. Means: I don't know beforehand which content to be distributed to which column. It my be aligned and sized dynamically depending on the content. Or is there any bootstrap component that can achieve the same effect, but without having to pre-define which content is to be shown in which column?

Comment: Bootstrap Grid System automatically will adjust the content for you as Bs is a ready made framework. Search for some examples on Google.

Comment: I know bootstrap very well, but afaik I must *predefine* the columns, and fill each column with content explicit! Why I want is eg passing a very very long text into just *one* div, and let the css align the text into two column bejond certain screen size. If you know this is possible with bootstrap, please give an example. I never found a bootstrap solution on this.

Comment: Don't take my word for it, but I've used bootstrap grid system for all my clients sites. However, test it yourself, it's pretty easy. I've never done what you're trying to achieve so I would not know where to start.